# Spotify Authenticate 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: javascript, request, http-post, spotify

I'm attempting to authenticate through Spotify's Web API and I'm trying to get refresh and access tokens. I have gotten the authentication code from user's redirecting but I constantly get the 400 status code error. I've tried many solutions posted but I have no idea why none of it is working.

I have also changed params to body and I have also tried to just put everything into the url.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[Related screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4HRs.png)

Comment: Solved! The problem was that my redirect uri was not the same as the one used to redirect in the first place. Reading was a simple fix.

Comment: https://github.com/Pau1fitz/react-spotify check out this project, might give you some ideas with the spotify api